# Problem opening a PLECS blockset in MATLAB

Tags: power-electronics, dc-dc-converter, simulation, matlab, simulink

A friend of mine sent his simulation of a converter for which he had used PLECS. It is in the format "example.slx".

I have MATLAB R2017b. I downloaded the PLECS block set for MATLAB and activated it using the trial license. But when I try to open his simulation, I get an error saying that the source file was made in a newer version (2017b). The problem is that even I have the same version of MATLAB.

I tried to then load the file and convert it to its previous version (2016b). After this, I was able to open the slx file, but there was just a plain yellow PLECS subsystem which was empty inside. How do I access this simulation?

Comment: This is a matlab support query not an EE question. Make sure both version (matlab and plecs) are aligns

Comment: They both are the same versions.

Comment: Same toolboxes?

Comment: @JonRB yeah. The same toolboxes as well as the same versions.